# Apache tomcat maven plugin compiling on non-existing version of Java

Tags: java, maven, javacompiler, tomcat8.5

I am trying to integrate my maven project with Tomcat server 8.5. Without integration, everything works fine. I replaced maven-compiler-plugin with tomcat7-maven-plugin in pom.xml and did other configurations. After that mvn install, mvn clean install and mvn tomcat7:deploy everything is failing with below exception.

```
TestServiceCSV.java:[345,48] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
```

So clearly the compilation is being performed using java 1.5, whereas my jdk version is 1.8.0_144. Additional details below:

```
>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T02:58:13-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

>java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have set the Installed JRE in Eclipse as the JDK. Also the build path for my project reflects same.

```
>echo $MAVEN_HOME
C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.2

>echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

Tomcat version 8.5.23

POM.xml entry

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>  
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>  
<server>TomcatServer</server>    
<username>admin</username>  
<password>xxxx</password>   
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Why could the compilation is being performed on 1.5 instead of the actual version?

Comment: Tomcat version 8.5.23.

Comment: "_I replaced maven-compiler-plugin with tomcat7-maven-plugin_" - **don't**. You have removed the section of the `pom.xml` that told Maven what version of Java to use. Why did you think you needed to _replace_ the compiler plugin rather than just **add** the tomcat plugin?

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Default source level](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-compiler-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/AbstractCompilerMojo.java#L96) of the compiler plugin is 1.5. The `compiler:compile` goal is bound to the `compile` phase of the [default lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). You always have to set the [source and target](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) levels if you want to use advanced language features from release 6 on.